# blend file opens with default cube instead of file's objects

Tags: objects

I am working on a modeling project in Blender 2.8. yesterday, I saved my progress and closed. now, when I try to open that file, it shows the default blender scene with cube,camera and light. I tried pressing Alt + H, nothing is hidden. An usual new blender scene is around 500 kb. But my file is 6.5mb. But can't see my objects. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should look at File menu > Recovery > Auto Save

[image: File menu > Recovery > Auto Save]

By default it located in path like \AppData\Local\Temp\

Seems like you have overridden you project with default scene..

Comment: This happened to me when the computer bluescreened unexpectedly. Perhaps that's a reason this can occur. In my case, the file size didn't change, but the result was the same.